# render angular route inside another page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am novice to angularjs. i want to know that is there any way to render html template based on route inside div of other page. let me explain with an example.
`/Employee/Add` is route which show a `add.html` template to add new employee.

can i render this `add.html` or `/Employee/Add` route in other 'abc.html' page ??. i know we can use `ng-include` directive to render any html template. but i am looking based on `route`.

is that possible ??

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking. It also helps to know which router you use, ngRoute or ui-router. Please show some relevant code

Comment: I am using ngRoute. i have injected `$routeProvider, $locationProvider, $provide, $httpProvider` in configuration module.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using UI-router.  Your basically creating a child state. Common use case is to create Tabs within a page.  It would look something like this:

```
  .state('league.games', {
    url: '/games',
    views: {
      'tabContent': {
        templateUrl: 'app/games/games.html',
        controller: 'GamesCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
          initialData: ['$stateParams', 'gamesInitialDataService',
            function($stateParams, gamesInitialDataService) {
              return gamesInitialDataService.getData($stateParams.leagueId);
            }]
        }
      }
    }
  })
```